# python-ldap OS X 10.6 and Python 2.6

Tags: python, django, python-ldap

Trying to install python-ldap for my Django project -- so far tried easy_install, pip, as well as building myself, but still getting the same errors:

```
dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_ldap.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ldap_create_assertion_control_value
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_ldap.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_ldap.so
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem and solution are documented [here](http://projects.skurfer.com/posts/2011/python_ldap_lion/).

Summary: The 10.7.{0,1} system tools and headers are all from OpenLDAP 2.4.x while the libraries are from OpenLDAP 2.2.0. The solution is to build the OpenLDAP libs to match the system headers and link python-ldap with those.

All credit goes to [Rob McBroom](http://www.skurfer.com/).

Answer (score 7):

pip install python-ldap==2.3.13 did the trick for me (Mac OS X 10.6)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error under 10.7 (Lion) using `easy_install` and `pip`. Manually installing 2.3.13 was the answer there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify setup.cfg to get this to work on OS X. Here's what I did:

```
wget http://python-ldap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-ldap/?view=tar --output-document=python-ldap.tar.gz
tar xvf python-ldap.tar.gz
cd python-ldap
```

Modify the following lines in setup.cfg:

```
library_dirs = /usr/local/lib
include_dirs = /usr/local/include /usr/include/sasl
libs = ldap lber sasl2 ssl crypto
```

Then continue with "normal" installation:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same thing :/

Comment: I have decided to go with python-ldap 2.3.13 -- it seems work when built from source.