# Installing python ldap module under cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I am trying to install the basic ldap python module under cygwin. The following is failing:

```
%easy_install ldap
Searching for ldap...
..
No local packages or download links found for ldap
```

I am using cherrypy for an app which is running fine in Ubuntu, and planning to port it to cygwin so I can run the app under my Win7 lapop.

(I could install a Django-specific module django-auth-ldap, and tried to import that as ldap, but this does not seem to have an initialize method that the basic ldap module has.)

PS: I forgot to mention trying python-ldap, but 'easy_install python-ldap' fails due to some compilation errors:

```
.....
.....
Modules/constants.c: In function `LDAPinit_constants':
Modules/constants.c:153:1: error: `LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE' undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/constants.c:153:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Modules/constants.c:363:29: error: `LDAP_CONTROL_RELAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: django-auth-ldap depends on python-ldap; it doesn't replace it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another stackoverflow page came to rescue:  [python-ldap OS X 10.6 and Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475118/python-ldap-os-x-10-6-and-python-2-6)

The final solution:

```
pip install python-ldap==2.3.13
```

Noting it here so people facing this in cygwin can use this post.

Comment: indeed `pip` is usually the answer

Comment: I am not familiar on the difference between pip vs. easy_install, but they both failed at same points during compilations. I think the specific version of python-ldap (2.3.13) is the real solver here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not `easy_install python-ldap` you want?

The Django LDAP authorization middleware is middleware - which is to say that it can't be used in the same manner as a Python module. It is designed to wrap a WSGI application.

See the [Django Middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) for more information.

Comment: I forgot to mention trying to install python-ldap, but that fails as well:    Modules/constants.c: In function `LDAPinit_constants':
Modules/constants.c:153:1: error: `LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE' undeclared (firs
t use in this function)
Modules/constants.c:153:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only onc
e for each function it appears in
Modules/constants.c:363:29: error: `LDAP_CONTROL_RELAX' undeclared (first use in
 this function)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1