# Installing py-ldap on Mac OS X Mavericks (missing sasl.h)

Tags: python, ldap, osx-mavericks

I can't seem to be able to get the python ldap module installed on my OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 machine.

Kernel details:
uname -a
Darwin  13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

I tried what was suggested here:
http://projects.skurfer.com/posts/2011/python_ldap_lion/

But when I try to use pip I get a different error

Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:10: fatal error: 'sasl.h' file not found

*#include sasl.h

I also tried what was suggested here:
[python-ldap OS X 10.6 and Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475118/python-ldap-os-x-10-6-and-python-2-6)

But with the same error.

I am hoping someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

using pieces from both @hharnisc and @mick-t answers.

```
pip install python-ldap \
   --global-option=build_ext \
   --global-option="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/sasl"
```

Comment: I don't have sudo permission on mac and this just did the trick !

Comment: This worked for me on Yosemite also. I didn't need to install anything macports or homebrew related for this particular install. Thanks!

Comment: This also works on El Capitan / 10.11 with System Integrity Protection on.

Comment: I was running into problems manually creating the link as in @hharnisc's solution (`ln: /usr/include: Operation not permitted`, even as sudo), but this worked on El Capitan.

Comment: to fix the issue about permissions and also isolate libraries installation, I suggest using virtualenv:
   "python -m virtualenv /yoursource; /yoursouhce/bin/pip install blah"
this will install everything local to your project and avoid clashing with other projects.

Comment: That answer is still valid under Mojave 10.14.3

Answer (score 32):

**A workaround** 
/usr/include appears to have moved

```
$ xcrun --show-sdk-path    
$ sudo ln -s <the_path_from_above_command>/usr/include /usr/include
```

Now run pip install!

Comment: I just saw this, no luck.

Comment: awesome ! this just fixed a lot of things on my side

Comment: Worked on OSX Mavericks for me.

Comment: Worked for me on Yosemite.  As a one-liner: ``sudo ln -s `xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include /usr/include``.

Comment: This no longer works on El Capitan if you have [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016227-DontLinkElementID_19) enabled. The other method (passing `-I` to pip) works.

Answer (score 24):

In my particular case, I couldn't simply use the `pip` arguments noted in other answers because I'm using it with `tox` to install dependencies from a requirements.txt file, and I need my tox.ini to remain compatible with non-Mac environments.

I was able to resolve this in much simpler fashion: exporting `CFLAGS` such that it adds an include path to the sasl headers already installed by Xcode:

```
$ pip install python-ldap
    ...
    building '_ldap' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/Modules
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.19 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/Users/bc/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
    Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:10: fatal error: 'sasl.h' file not found
    #include <sasl.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

$ export CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/sasl"

$ pip install python-ldap
...
Successfully installed python-ldap-2.4.19
```

Depending on whether or not you use any userspace-friendly Python tools (I use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)), you may have to prefix your pip commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Worked for me in OS X Yosemite.  Thanks!

Comment: And High Sierra too. +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I'm using Macports on my Mac and I have cyrus-sasl2 installed which provides sasl.h in  /opt/local/include/sasl/. You can pass options to build_ext using pip's global-option argument. To pass the include PATH to /opt/local/include/sasl/sasl.h run pip like this:

`pip install  python-ldap --global-option=build_ext  --global-option="-I/opt/local/include/sasl"`

Alternatively you could point it to whatever the output from `xcrun --show-sdk-path` provides. On my box that's:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk`

Then you need to determine the PATH to the sasl header files. For me that's:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/sasl/`

Let me know if that helps or you need a hand.

Comment: sudo pip install python-ldap --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/sasl"
Downloading/unpacking python-ldap
  Error <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm> while getting https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-ldap/python-ldap-2.4.19.tar.gz#md5=b941bf31d09739492aa19ef679e94ae3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-ldap/)

Answer (score 1):

I used a combination of posts I found about this problem (including this one) to eventually come up with this (copied from a larger script):

```
export XC_SDK=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
export USR_INC=$XC_SDK/usr/include
export PATH=$USR_INC:$PATH

echo "installing python-ldap"
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install python-ldap
```

You can test it with `python -c "import ldap"`

The main reason I didn't follow the advice of @hharnisc was that on my local machine /usr/local had not moved, so I just temporarily put $XC_SDK before it on the path, and that seems to work.

some sources:
[how to install PIL on Macosx 10.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449304/how-to-install-pil-on-macosx-10-9?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running buildout.

I fixed it, first finding the sasl.h file:

```
mdfind -name sasl.h
```

then defining the corresponding CFLAGS environment variable:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include/sasl"
```

and finally running buildout again.