# how to install PIL on Macosx 10.9?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

When I try to install PIL library on Macosx 10.9.2, it's giving following error, how to install it.

> $: sudo pip install pillow
>
> cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.2/include/freetype2 -I/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow/libImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
>
> clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa

Answer (score 2):

following line helped me.

> sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow

Answer (score 0):

This was because OS10.9 changes its cc compiler, so 'cc' can not compile some python libs.
I tried to fix this problem by replacing my cc compiler with older version gcc. 
First, you should install brew.

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

and install gcc-4.2

```
$ sudo brew install apple-gcc42
```

delete current cc. its just a symbolic link from clang, so you do not need to backup it.

```
$ sudo rm -f /usr/bin/cc
```

create new symbolic link, cc -> gcc-4.2

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/cc
```

test if you change it successful.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep cc
```

if it shows

```
$ cc -> /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
```

that means you successfully changed your cc compiler. And you can install your python lib like PIL or pillow.